# Linkedin API Webhooks

Tags: linkedin-api, webhooks

We are developing a platform to help freelancers schedule #linkedin posts for their clients and manage comments on those posts.

I understand from the documentation that LinkedIn provides webhooks for apps to get notified when a Page post receives comments but I can't find a way to enable that feature. At the moment we are basically query the API frequently enough to make it look like it is a webhook but that is not a proper solution.

Is it a very restricted feature just like video UGC posts (which would be nice to have as well)?
Or can we apply somehow?
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to your question about Webhooks?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Looks like you need some insider contact...

Comment: see e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/linkedin/shared/api-guide/webhook-validation?context=linkedin/context